# InDesign jsx opening files with specific options

Tags: macos, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am trying to batch process `.indd` files created many years ago on old versions of InDesign.

I have 2 goals:

1. Open `.indd` files without having to manually click on the
   dialogs:- *"Update linked images? (select 'update')"*, *"font errors
   (select 'Skip')"*
2. Save files to `.indd`, current versions native format, attaching `_cc2020` to their original filename.

Here's how I am doing so far:

```js
// Opening files

// specify source folder
path = '~/Desktop/source_dir';

// list files in the folder
var my_folder = new Folder(path);
list_of_files = my_folder.getFiles();

// open file(s)
fileObj = app.open(list_of_files);


// saving files
// get current documents
myDoc = app.activeDocument;

// save current document with specific name
myDoc.save(File('~/Desktop/test01.indd'));
```

I could not find ways to suppress (or provide preset default value to) the two dialogs.
Could someone please enlighten me how I can achieve this?

ps. I found providing `false` as second argument will suppress font dialogs, but *"update images"* dialogs still persists.

```js
// open file(s)
fileObj = app.open(list_of_files, false);
```

resource I've been referring to https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppress dialogues with

```js
app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevels.NEVER_INTERACT;
```